# Range of frequency ($−∞$ to $+∞$) in continuum of harmonic oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

I am reading this paper on quantum Langevin equations and input-output theory https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.31.3761. Here we define the bath interacting with our quantum system as a continuum of harmonic oscillators

$$H_{B} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \omega b^{\dagger}(\omega)b(\omega) d\omega .$$

However, later on the limits on integral are changed to $-\infty$ to $\infty$. How does we define a quantum harmonic oscillator with negative frequencies ? And since the frequency decides the energy level spacing, how does it make sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the significance of negative frequency in Fourier transform?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46948/what-is-the-significance-of-negative-frequency-in-fourier-transform)

Comment: @Miyase Thank you for the suggestion. I understood why negative frequencies are needed in the Fourier transform. I still can't make a link with that answer and this question. In the Fourier transform, we have complex signals and summing over all the frequencies (for both anti-clockwise and clockwise rotations) gives us the positive and negative values. However, here we are integrating all possible values of operators whose energy eigen values depend on frequency.

Comment: What modes do the $b(\omega)$ populate? Since there is a lower bound on the frequency, these modes are likely not *plane-wave* modes but rather sinusoidal modes, which is likely due to the boundary conditions at the coupling mirrors of the cavity. The sinusoidal mode functions include both positive and negative frequency parts, and hence we "re-parameterize" the frequencies as being positive.   I don't have access to the paper, but I would guess that later on they introduce a density of states, which is zero for $\omega<0$, but sending limit to infinity makes the integral easier to compute.

Comment: @march Thanks for the comment. The paper describes the spectral density of bath as of white noise. So, I don't think it is sinusoidal modes. Furthermore, it is not assumed in paper that for negative frequencies the states are zero.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be explained in the paper already. I quote (paragraph below equation 2.2)

> The Hamiltonian (2.1) is, of course, an idealization. In practice, the range of $\omega$ is $(0,\infty)$, but a range of $(-\Omega,\infty)$ can arise when we go into a frame rotating with angular frequency $\Omega$ as is common in quantum optics, and it is certainly the case that $\Omega$ is very large compared with the typical bandwidths obtained.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When it says "go into a frame" it doesn't mention about which operator we are moving into a frame with. In a rotated frame about an operator $U_{r}$ the states are $\rho_{r} \rightarrow U^{\dagger}_{r}\rho_{S}U_{r}.$ So about what operator are we rotating here such that in that frame the limits make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Because the integral is zero if evaluated from $-\infty$ to $0$, the integral defined only in the right interval has to be exactly equal to the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, defined in the total interval, i.e.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\omega b^\dagger(\omega)b(\omega)d\omega=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\omega b^\dagger(\omega)b(\omega)d\omega+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\omega b^\dagger(\omega)b(\omega)d\omega=$$$$=0+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\omega b^\dagger(\omega)b(\omega)d\omega$$
This can be useful to use certain properties of an integral defined in a symmetric interval, e.g. if $f(\omega)$ is even, then $\int_{-a}^{a}f(\omega)d\omega=2\int_{0}^{a}f(\omega)d\omega$ and if $f(\omega)$ is odd $\int_{-a}^{a}f(\omega)d\omega=0$. Clearly if the interval isn't symmetric that property can't be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please clarify how you identify $\int^{0}_{-\infty} \omega b^{\dagger}(\omega )b(\omega) d\omega$ is 0 ?